# c# IEnumerable property. Does adding an item to the collection call the mutator or just the accessor?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Suppose I have

```
class A
{

 public List<B> LiProperty
 {
    get;
    set { //will I get called when someone calls A::LiProperty.Add()? }
 }

}
```

Then

```
A a = new A();
a.LiProperty.Add(new B());
```

Will the mutator ever be called?

My instincts say that get is returning a pointer to the list so the add method is being called directly on the object, but then again C# does some funky stuff sometimes with immutable types. Anybody know the answer for certain?

Comment: What is a mutator? And `List<T>` is not immutable. And what sort of "funky stuff" does C# do with immutable types?

Comment: Neither your code nor anything in the C# language has anything to do with immutability.

Comment: @Adam, sorry for my archaic terminology. A mutator is served by the set function and an accessor is served by the get.

Comment: @SLaks "nor anything in the C# language has anything to do with immutability." Strings are immutable as well as some other types. I am not saying IEnumerables are immutable, I am just a little confused about when the reference gets changed on the IEnumerable type.

Comment: @JonathanHenson: That's not the C# language.  Also, you aren't using IEnumerable.

Comment: The members defined in IEnumerable form an immutable interface.  However, most implementations of IEnumerable, including `List<T>`, are _not_ immutable.

Comment: @SLaks List inherits from IEnumerable, I was using the term in a more generic meaning.

Comment: @SLaks I retagged it. I had tagged it that way because I was curious if an alteration to the list reassigned its reference. That is why I was concerned about mutability/immutability. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Slaks,  `List<T>` implements IEnumerable;  And he is using the term Mutator to refer the the setter, I have not seen this before but it is a useful, valid way to describe a setter, it does change (or mutate) the property the setter is for.  Was this such a leap for you ?

Comment: @CharlesBretana: I'm the one that asked what a mutator was. I was simply asking for clarification, which the OP provided. Rough morning?

Comment: @JonathanHenson: What SLaks is getting at is that the idea of immutability is one of *convention* (in other words, the way the type is written to prevent changes after it is created) rather than anything to do with the language itself. Strings (as with all other types) behave in the same manner as any reference type; it's only the convention that it exposes no properties that can be set and no functions that cause side effects that make it immutable.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: Exactly.  Note that it is possible to have a language with baked-in support for immutability, where the compiler must prove that a type really is immutable.  C# does not have such a concept.

Comment: For those curious about the choice of words mutator/accessor functions, I learned that in my first c++ course in college when we were learning encapsulation for OOP. It is actually written that way in my text book.

Comment: @Adam thank you for the clarification. SLaks, I will be more careful with my choice of words next time--it is also a useful distinction. Thank you both.

Comment: @Adam, yes I saw your question. Your question was clearly aimed at the goal of helping the op... by soliciting more information about the problem/issue he was having. That's what I understand this forum to be about. But it would be hard to interpret the comment "That's not the C# language. Also, you aren't using IEnumerable" as constructive or helpful, it seems to be just critical... And no, I have not had a bad day, are you offeriong to improve it in some way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the property is to change it to point to another different `List<T>`.  Adding an object to the list is ***not*** changing *which* `List<T>` the property points to.  The code will not call the setter unless you wrote `a.LiProperty = new List<T>();`

Comment: I think I understand now, I suppose I just need to quit thinking low-level in c#. That is why, now that I think about it, string.replace() doesn't modify the actual string, like it did in c++, it gives you a new reference to assign to your object. Thinking of it this way, it doesn't matter if the type is mutable or immutable. The setter will never be called until you reassign the reference. string.replace() doesn't reassign the reference, it returns you a new one to do with as you please.

Comment: @JonathanHenson: Exactly; the `A` class does not know anything about the way that you interact with the reference held by its `LiProperty`. It knows when you retrieve it and when you set it back to another (or the same) reference, but that's it.

Answer (score 6):

Your instinct is correct. In your code snippet above, the `get` accessor is called, and the `Add` method is called on the List returned.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Like any other property, the setter will only run if you write  `LiProperty = something`.
That will replace replace the list with a new list instance (unless you do something funky in your setter)

In general, [collection properties should be readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx).

Comment: What if I need to handle the event where something is added to the list?

Comment: @JonathanHenson: Then you should use a `Collection<T>` and override `InsertItem`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx

Comment: Or, alternatively, use a collection type that exposes a modification event, such as `BindingList` or `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

In .net, a property of type T is nothing more than a link to a pair of methods, one of which has the signature: `T get_method( [optional arguments, in case of indexed property] );` and one of which has the signature: `void set_method(T value, [optional arguments, in case of indexed property] );`.  In C#, the set_method is only called when the property is on the left half of an assignment operator; otherwise, the get_method is called(*).  *Note that in .net, a property generally has no way of knowing what is done with the result it returns, nor any way of getting notified when the caller is done with the returned object*.

(*) In vb.net, it is permissible in some cases to write code which would appear to pass a property by reference.  The actual compiler behavior in such cases is to 'get' the property to a temp, pass that temp by reference, call the function, and then 'set' the property to the value the function left in temp.

A more useful pattern from a code perspective would be to have a method which calls a specified delegate with the field backing the property as a 'ref' parameter.  This would make it possible to do something like:

```
  MyShape.ActOnBounds((ref Rectangle bounds) => {bounds.x -= bounds.width/2; bounds.width *= 2;});
```

and have MyShape act upon the changed value of "bounds" without having to copy or create any superfluous instances of Rectangle.  Unfortunately, while such a transformation could be reasonably performant (especially if ActOnBounds could be a static method accepting one or more a generic type parameters, and call the supplied routine with ref parameters of those types), the client-side code is a bit ugly.

Incidentally, even if .net didn't have struct types, the above pattern could still be useful (better than get-manipulate-set) with primitive types or reference properties where the reference itself may have to be changed, since it allows the use of things like Interlocked.Increment and Interlocked.CompareExchange.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose a list in such a way that you can find out when it is updated, one way to do that is to define an immutable struct type which holds a reference to your object and implements IList by redirecting all IList methods to private methods of your object (which will in turn perform then on the list and act upon them as appropriate).  Note that despite being an immutable struct, the new type would act with reference semantics (meaning that making a copy of the struct and calling the "Add" method on it would cause the new item to be visible in both the original and copied structs).

Doing things in this way would avoid boxing in the scenario where methods are performed directly on the returned list property (e.g. `myThing.LiProperty.Add("George");` and in the scenario where the returned type is used to create a variable (e.g. `var myList = myThing.LiProperty;`.  Boxing would occur if and when the returned object was assigned to a variable, or passed to a parameter, of an interface type (e.g. IList).

Comment: If the type of the property is `IList` (which it would need to be in order not to expose your internal value type), then the value will be boxed as the resulting type of the `var` variable will be `IList`. This would also happen even if you work directly on the property itself (no intermediate variable storage). Why would I choose this approach rather than simply inheriting from `List<T>`?

Comment: @Adam Robinson: The return type of the property would be the structure type which implements IList.  Note that the property would have to be read-only in this scenario, but there's no way to get around that and still have the semantics I believe you want.  If you allow someone to use the property setter with a passed-in IList, you would have no way of knowing when an object was added to the passed-in list.  If your intention would be to replace the contents of your list with the contents of a passed-in list, you should use a method for that (e.g. ReplaceContents).

Comment: Which then requires that you expose what *should* be an internal type. The caller has no business knowing that you're using this (somewhat odd, but admittedly effective) approach. Again, though, I ask: why would I want to do this rather than simply inherit from `List<T>`?

Comment: @Adam Robinson: What would you propose to gain by inheriting from `List<T>`?  The "Add" method of `List<T>` is not virtual, so you can't hook it to find out when stuff is added to the list.  You could use an `IList<T>` implementation--that's what my proposed struct would be.  You're correct that the struct would ideally be a private type, but since the only exposed members would mirror those of its `IList<T>` implementation, and since exposing the type would allow calling code to be more efficient in many cases, I don't really see much downside.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: BTW, if I had my druthers, it would be possible to declare a struct type for this type of situation and tag it in such a way as to forbid outside code from persisting instances of it (the struct could define an implicit typecast to a persistable type).  Unfortunately, no such ability exists within the framework.

Comment: If not `List<T>`, then some other collection type. Or use one of the several built-in collection types that already support change notification (`BindingList`, `ObservableCollection`, etc.) Or, for that matter, simply follow your approach and implement as a *reference* type. I'm not clear on what you think would be gained by using a value type.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Using an exposed value type offers the same semantics as would be achieved if one substituted class for the struct, but the struct would offer improved performance in common usage scenarios.  I don't see that a struct would offer outside code any opportunity to do anything it shouldn't, would expect the scenarios where it would impede performance to be much less common than those where it would help, and basically don't see a downside.

Comment: My point is that I don't see how it provides any *updside*. In what way would this offer better performance? Both cases get around boxing (yours if you expose the private type, mine simply because it's a reference type to begin with) and in both cases you're dealing with heap memory. I don't see how performance could be different with either approach, but yours requires that you expose what should be a hidden type, indicating to the user that you're doing something "smelly".

Comment: @Adam Robinson: I guess if your object holds a field of the list-wrapper type, it could simply return the object in that field whenever someone gets LiProperty.  One otherwise-unnecessary object reference field and one otherwise-unnecessary heap allocation, but on the whole not too bad.  The struct approach is a bigger advantage with indexed properties (the struct holds the root object and the index), where creating an excess heap object for every possible indexer may be expensive or impractical.